# Pyspark return RDD after sorting

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

How can I return an RDD after an ordering operation. I would like to order by one value, take the top results and order them on a second value.

For example,

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, "a", 10), (2, "b", 9), (3, "c", 8)])

res = rdd.takeOrdered(2, lambda x: x[0]) # sort on first value
# sort on second value
out = sc.parallelize(res).sortBy(lambda x: x[2]).collect()
```

But can I have `res` be an RDD and do it in one step? Something like

```
rdd.takeOrdered(2, lambda x: x[0])\
   .sortBy(lambda x: x[2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends how many elements you've taken in the first step, if it's small, then there's no need to redistribute it anymore, just sort it in the driver with the `sorted` function:

```
sorted(res, key=lambda x: x[2])
# [(2, 'b', 9), (1, 'a', 10)]
```

If on the hand you take a lot of elements in the first step, you can sort the rdd, zip it with index and then use filter to take the first few elements, which doesn't collect rdd to the driver, and you can continue sort it based on the third element in the tuple:

```
(rdd.sortBy(lambda x: x[0])
    .zipWithIndex()
    .filter(lambda x: x[1] <= 1)
    .map(lambda x: x[0])
    .sortBy(lambda x: x[2])
).collect()

# [(2, 'b', 9), (1, 'a', 10)]
```

Comment: ah, the `zipWithIndex` works for what I was trying to do. Thankyou